# If $b \mid a$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then does the following list exhaust all possible cases?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $b \mid a$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then does the following list exhaust all possible cases?

- $a = b^c$ for some positive integer $c$
- $a = db$ for some positive integer $d$

If this list is not exhaustive, then what are the other cases to consider so that the list is exhaustive?

Comment: $a=db$ is the general conclusion of $b|a$. $a=b^c$ also fits in this conclusion, as then $a=b^{c-1}b$ so $d= b^{c-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @insipidintegrator!  Please write that out as an actual answer so that I can upvote and then accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b|a$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z_+$,  then the general conclusions are:

- $|b|\leq |a|$ (this can sometimes be used in proofs which go as: from original hypotheses, prove $a|b$. prove $b|a$. Then conclude $a=b$. )
- there exists some positive integer $d$ such that $a=db$.

This also includes the special case that $a=b^c$, as we can write $a=b^{c-1}b$ so that $d=b^{c-1}$ in this case.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say $d = b^{c-1}$ in that last equation (instead of $d = a = b^{c-1}$), @insipidintegrator?

Comment: Yea, my bad i edited it.

Comment: +1 and accept!  Thanks.

Comment: As presumably the "$+$" in $\Bbb Z_+$ does not stand for addition but instead for either $\geq0$ or $>0$ (it beats me why people would want to replace a clear notation like $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb N_{>0}=\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ with a notation that reads like a riddle), taking the absolute values in the first point appears to be redundant.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I don’t know. I used to use $\mathbb N$ but found out that people are always squibbling over the inclusion of $0$. So I converted to $\mathbb Z_+$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator My points are that (1) the plus symbol is not mathmatically related to positivity, but more importantly (2) the notation $\Bbb Z_+$ could equally validly be used to include $0$ or to exclude it. So introducing the notation just complicates the landscape, and does not even resolve the difficuly that gave rise to its invention.